# IF event has occurred at X location within Y days, return Z value (Excel or Google Sheets)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have an Events data set of recurring events with each event as a row and each column as data associated with that event. There is a date and location for each event. New locations are added on a regular basis. Sometimes these events stop going to a particular location. I have a separate Locations sheet with a list of locations, and I would like to classify locations as "Active" or "Inactive" to know if they are actively receiving this event.

The events are health outreach clinics, but you could also think of them as a package being delivered or a site visit being conducted.

I want to classify locations under this typology:

- "Active" if event has occurred within the last 90 days
- "Inactive" if event last occurred over 90 days ago

What formula should I use?

Here is a sample file and screenshots:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tn1tSza-hza1qVKotEcMyNBktZTlExBB5MQBlcyfkP8/edit?usp=sharing

[Events Sheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxZNn.png)

[Locations Sheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfPgd.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Next time please include your own attempt or at least let people know what efforts you have made to solve your case :]

Comment: @TerryW That's fair! Sorry about that.

My guess was that it should involve using "IF" calculating the days between "TODAY()" and the most recent date that the event occurred, but I didn't know how to first query the most recent event at the location matching the name. So I didn't really know how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in **B2**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>""), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 FILTER(Events!B2:B, Events!A2:A>=TODAY()-90))), "active", "inactive"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Using Excel**:

In Cell `B2` of your `Locations` sheet, enter the following formula and drag it down.

```
=IFERROR(IF((TODAY()-AGGREGATE(14,6,Events!A:A/(Events!B:B=A2),1))<=90,"Active","Inactive"),"Not Applicable")
```

> Firstly, `Events!A:A/(Events!B:B=A2)` will return an array of dates "filtered" by the given location, then use **AGGREGATE** function to return the largest date from the array, then subtract that date from **TODAY()**, if the result is `<=90` days, return `Active`, otherwise `Inactive`.
>
> If there is no date can be found for the given location, **IFERROR** function will return `Not Applicable` as a result.

---

**Using Google-Sheets**:

In Cell `B2` of your `Locations` sheet, enter the following formula and drag it down.

```
=IF((TODAY()-MAXIFS(Events!A:A,Events!B:B,A2))<=90,"Active","Inactive")
```

> The logic is to use **MAXIFS** to return the latest date by the given location, then use it to compare with **TODAY()** and the rest is the same as previous formula except this formula can only return `Inactive` for location that does not have any visits but the previous one can return `Not Applicable` for the ones that have never been visited.
>
> This function also works in Excel if your version of Excel has **MAXIFS** function.